# This asp.net code is not fetching any data why?

Tags: asp.net

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();  
  DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Utility.GetPumaConString(), 
  CommandType.Text, @"SELECT name,IsBlocked FROM 
  ht_cust where type=14 and DealerId<>19");
  return ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Umm, there is no data that satifies the where condition?

Comment: danish When i execute the query in sql it returns data .

Comment: There's an issue with your connection string?  Do you get any errors?  Are you swallowing exceptions in `Utility.GetPumaConString` or `SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset`?

Comment: no i am not getting any error.

Comment: still it is not working ,after editing.Ganesh_Devlekar

Comment: Can anybody till me other method of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly try this on your project.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("your connectiongstring");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT name,IsBlocked FROM ht_cust where type=14 and DealerId<>19", connection);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
connection.Open();
da.Fill(dt);

//bind it to the grid
gv.DataSource = dt;
gv.DataBind();

connection.Close();
```